# Calling methods inside AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

What is the difference if I call methods within *AsyncTask* [1] **vs** if I write code directly in it [2]? If I write all my code within *AsyncTask* then it's really cluttered. I want to create separate methods to do this or maybe even separate classes.

[1]:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, String > {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {
    loadXML();
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    setValues();
  }
}

public void loadXML() {
  //loadsXML
}
public void setValues() {
  //Sets values to textViews
}
```

[2]:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, String > {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {
    //Load XML from web
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //Set TextView from result obtained in doInBackground
  }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. Is there a problem you are having?

Comment: I haven't tested it, I just wanted to know if the AsyncTask can be used in this way before I move my clutter into methods. :D

Comment: Ok, you have my permission. Carry on...

Comment: :) Please go with the methods instead of inlining the xml loading code for the sake of modularity and code quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it per se, but keep in mind that the methods are still running on the AsyncTask's thread. So if you want to modify the UI thread, for example, you should still use `publishProgress`/`onProgressUpdate` (meaning you'll need a reference to the AsyncTask instance).

Comment: So if I call a method in: `protected void onPostExecute(String result) {//here}` which will setText for textView it would not work?

Comment: No that will be fine. I meant during execution. (For example, if you needed to access the UI thread from `loadXML()`)

Answer (score 0):

There´s no diference because the code will run in the same thread. Feel to write as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

No difference, But...

With the [1] approach the program becomes more modular and follows object oriented principle.

With the [2] approach it become more clumsy if you want to include some more methods in it.

and the third approach [3] which I personally may prefer doing is to expose the `loadXML()` method in separate class say `XMLLoader` to encapsulate the complexities of xml parsing and loading and use this class in `AsyncTask` to load the XML .

Similarly `setValues()` could be exposed within my android activity view which should be passed to AsyncTask as a parameter.

Note that there are other ways to solve this in modular way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used a seperate class and put my AsyncTask inside it. Then I call this AsyncTask from my MainAcitvity like this:
`AnotherClass.MyAsyncTask.execute();`. It gives me an error saying non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context.